# TypeError: this.element is undefined in Firefox 22.0 causing my site to be down

Tags: javascript, firefox, joomla

I was using Firefox 14 and our site ([www.o-sense.com](http://www.o-sense.com)) was working fine without issues. After the upgrade of FF to 22.0, the site start to be just blank!

When checking the Console tab in Firebug, we found this error:
TypeError: this.element is undefined

I really don't know from where this error came, and how to fix it!

We are using Joomla! 1.5.26 (latest version of 1.5), and I tried to disable all modules with no luck.

I appreciate your help guys.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using the developer tools and having it break on exception? More generally - what have you tried to resolve this issue?

Comment: Benjamin, thanks for the quick reply. I didn't tried Developer tools, what I did is a trial and error, disabled all the modules (maybe I can find where is the reason), I reached to disable everything and yet the error remain.

Comment: I'm working on a test page (http://o-sense.com/test2.html), I solved all the errors there and everything shall be normal, yet, it still appear as completely blank in FF, while in Chrome is OK....

Comment: I think the site still worked for you in FF 14 because it was being cached. It is highly probable that a change has been made to the template, plugin etc

Comment: @Lodder, I'm sure it is working fine on FF14, you can test now from your end :) and nothing was changed on the site, as I mentioned, I tried to disable all modules with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: I found the case, After I disabled the MooTools update plugin, the website start to working fine even in Firefox.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the case, After I disabled the MooTools update plugin, the website start to working fine even in Firefox.

Thanks for your help.